# Variable is not used

Tags: python, tkinter

this would be my first question up here so don't be mad if i do something wrong. I got this homework of guessing the secret number and i had to implement Tkinter in it. The problem is that the counter isn't working since the variable counter is not used. I get it, but i tough i code it as it should be, and it looks like not. And for another question, bellow else statement i used IF again, is this OK or do you practice different code.

```
    import Tkinter
    import random
    import tkMessageBox

    secret_number = random.randint(1, 10)

    window = Tkinter.Tk()

    greeting = Tkinter.Label(window, text="Welcome to the game " + "guess the secret number".upper() + ". You have 5 tries.\n Select a number between 1 and 10:")
    greeting.pack()


    guess = Tkinter.Entry(window)
    guess.pack()


    def check_guess():
        counter = 0
        if int(guess.get()) == secret_number:
            counter = counter + 1 #here it states "variable not used"
            result_text = "You guessed correctly! Secret number is %s! " % secret_number
        elif int(guess.get()) > secret_number:
            counter = counter + 1
            result_text = "Wrong. Your number is to HIGH! This was your %s try." % counter
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
            result_text = "Wrong. Your number is to LOW! This was your %s try." % counter
        if counter == 5 and guess != secret_number:
            print "Secret number was %s!" % secret_number

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result", result_text)


    submit = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Try your luck", command=check_guess)  # check_guess, not check_guess()
    submit.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime the function is called, `counter` will be set to 0, meaning it will never be equal to 5. A simple fix could be to use a global variable instead. Set `counter = 0` outside the function instead, and remove that line from the function. Instead, write `global counter` at the first line in the function. Something like this:

```
counter = 0
def check_guess():
    global counter
    if int(guess.get()) == secret_number:
    ...
```